# TSQL to drop tables from database if they appear in lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to drop some tables from *DatabaseOne* based on if they are marked for dropping in *LookupTable*.

*LookupTable* is similar to below in design:

```
    TableName        DropTable
=========================================
    TableA           Y
    TableB           Y
    TableC           N
    TableD           Y
```

So in this example, all except TableC would get dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
SELECT @SQL += N'DROP TABLE [' + name + '];'
FROM LookUpTable
WHERE DropTable = 'Y'
ORDER BY TableName 

select @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(2000)

declare CRS_TABLE cursor fast_forward for
SELECT N'DROP TABLE [' + TableName + '];'
FROM LookupTable
WHERE DropTable = 'Y'
ORDER BY TableName

open CRS_TABLE
fetch next from CRS_TABLE into @SQL
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    print @SQL
    EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @SQL
    fetch next from CRS_TABLE into @SQL
end
close CRS_TABLE
deallocate CRS_TABLE
```

If you have constraints on these tables, you'll need to drop those first.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL=(SELECT DISTINCT ( Stuff((SELECT '; DROP TABLE  ' + [TABLENAME]
                                       FROM   #TABLE1
                                       WHERE  DROPTABLE = 'Y'
                                       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ') ) LIST_OUTPUT
              FROM   #TABLE1)

    EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: what is `.VALUE(` ?

Comment: Value method returns scalar value from xml document. For more go through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx or https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-xml-methods-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Seems need to use dynamic query,

```
CREATE TABLE #LookUpTable
(
    TableName     VARCHAR(10),
    DropTable     VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO #LookUpTable
SELECT 'TableA',
       'Y'

INSERT INTO #LookUpTable
SELECT 'TableB',
       'Y'

INSERT INTO #LookUpTable
SELECT 'TableC',
       'N'

INSERT INTO #LookUpTable
SELECT 'TableD',
       'Y'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @SQL += N'DROP TABLE [' + TableName + '] GO '
FROM   #LookUpTable
WHERE  DropTable = 'Y'
ORDER BY
       TableName 

PRINT @sql

EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @sql

DROP TABLE #LookUpTable
```